# Groovy script run, debug and step into from code (without IDE), is that possible?

Tags: java, debugging, groovy

I'm exploring the use of Groovy as the default scripting language for my next project. Some basic requirements are:

1. load and run Groovy scripts, sending params in and getting results out, I know this can be done using GroovyShell or GroovyScriptEngine.
2. be able to run in debug mode stepping into the statements of the scripts (no need of managing breakpoints but execute statements in the code and take a look and the values of the variables in the current scope).

Yes, this is like a small IDE, but should be integrated into the app that manages running many scripts in parallel, and sending outputs of some scripts to inputs of other scripts (is a pipes and filters architecture http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PipesAndFilters.html).

I'm not sure if Groovy alone provides debugging and stepping into groovy code, or Java Platform Debugger Architecture should be used, or if this should be done by embedding an IDE into this system (it might be possible to embed Eclipse components).

These are my main concerns/doubts about the possibilities of using Groovy. any pointers are welcome.

Comment: what is the question? if about debugging - just look at other tools with groovy scripting language - for example `soapui`. there is no script debugging in it. just logging. you can debug one script in any groovy ide.

Comment: the question is if debugging and stepping of groovy code (execution of individual statements) is possible to do from groovy code (via GroovyShell, GroovyScriptEngine, or other mechanism), and getting values of variables in the current scope, without an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is "No easy way to embed debugging functionality in an application that I am aware of". Please provide workaround instructions to use companion IDE or start deep research for any open source projects that have embedded script debugger functionality... and become great friends to the related contributing developers :-).

**MORE INFORMATION:**

Anything is possible when working with open source software. Yes, you can build a debugger that hooks execution of script (assuming you can keep process/threads separate) to step, create/halt at breakpoints, read variables currently in memory, etc.

**Example:** SmartBear ReadyAPI **SoapUI NG PRO** v4.6+(?) includes some base debugging embedded in their **"Groovy Script" Test Step** editor pane. *(Disclaimer: SmartBear might have used other language or libraries to build their debugger features. I also am unsure if/when this feature will go to the SoapUI Open Source project - debugging is clearly noted as a PRO (paid) feature.)*

**Caveats:**

1. Implementing debugger functionality is a MAJOR feature. You need debugger development experience (and/or even more time) to build functionality unrelated to your actual application. Make sure you truly need this embedded debugging before proceeding.
2. You should start with existing open-source groovy debugger to embed in your application... if one exists. SmartBear SoapUI NG PRO would be a start... but PRO feature is not open source.